# How I can create an agent by dialogflow+python?

Tags: python, dialogflow-es

I do not found a method in https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2, which will create an agent.
Also, I do not found in Python dialogflow_v2 function which can create an agent.
How I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

I have created this below python code for creating an agent in google's dialogflow v2 API using python client.

```
from google.cloud import dialogflow

def create_agent(project_id, display_name):

    parent = "projects/" + project_id
    agents_client = dialogflow.AgentsClient()

    agent = dialogflow.Agent(
        parent=parent, display_name=display_name, default_language_code="en", time_zone="Asia/Colombo"
    )

    response = agents_client.set_agent(
        request={"agent": agent}
    )

    print("Agent created: {}".format(response))
```

To run this code, you need to set your service account authentication JSON as *GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS* environment variable in your system. Check this below link for more details,

https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#windows

- *project_id* is your Google's account project id under which you want to create a dialogflow agent.
- *display_name* is your dialogflow agent name to create.